# textout winapi with keyboard messages

Tags: winapi, textout

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

HDC             hdc;
PAINTSTRUCT     ps;
TCHAR           szBuffer[1];



switch (message)
{
case WM_CHAR:
    szBuffer[1] = (TCHAR) wParam;
    cout << wParam << " " << szBuffer[1] << " ";

    break;

case WM_PAINT:
    InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, TRUE);
    hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    SelectObject(hdc,GetStockObject(SYSTEM_FIXED_FONT));
    TextOut(hdc, 1, 1, szBuffer, 1);
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    return 0;
```

Hello all, 
I am trying to run the above code and simply print a single letter at a time on my window. However, I cannot seem to get the characters to appear on the window with the TextOut function but am able to display the characters in the terminal window. I am new to WinApi and am lost!

thanks in advance!

Comment: `static TCHAR szBuffer[2];` ... `szBuffer[0] = (TCHAR)wParam; szBuffer[1] = '\0';`

Comment: @JonathanPotter the joys of GDI text APIs that not only don't require null-terminated strings but also don't allow them outright... (Really, I wish the functions would accept -1 to mean null-terminated like the charset conversion functions :| ) I'm guessing that this person is coming from some other programming language (one with 1-based indexing) so I tried to reflect that in my answer :/ But yes, learning about null-terminated strings may be important

Comment: Do NOT have an InvalidateRect() call inside your WM_PAINT handler. InvalidateRect() is what you call to force WM_PAINT to be called in the first place. You might want to put it in your WM_CHAR handler though.

Comment: @andlabs: Yes it's best to get into good habits from the very start :)

Answer (score 3):

Your `szBuffer` is local to `WndProc()` and by default local variables in C have *automatic storage*: each time your `WndProc()` is called, a new `szBuffer` is created, so by the time your `WM_PAINT` is reached, whatever was typed in `WM_CHAR`was lost. You will need to store `szBuffer` somewhere else, such as outside `WndProc()`, or declare it as `static`, which will keep the buffer around (but beware that static storage is NOT safe for recursion).

Also in C the first element of an array has index 0, not 1; the line `szBuffer[1] = (TCHAR) wParam;` needs to be `szBuffer[0] = (TCHAR) wParam;` to do what you want.

---

Since I am running on the assumption you are new to C, see Jonathan Potter's comment about having an extra character in your strings whose value is zero (not the character code for the digit zero, but the numerical value 0, or `'\0'` or `L'\0'`). While `TextOut()` and the other GDI text drawing functions don't use these *null-terminated strings*, **everything else in C does**. Watch out.

---

And Joe Willcoxson's comment is also correct. `InvalidateRect()` queues the given rectangle as needing repaint. Using it in your `WM_PAINT` handler will cause you to always get `WM_PAINT` messages over and over again, which will have negative effects on performance as your programs become larger and larger.